# Fastest way to find the rank of a value in a given array

Tags: javascript, jquery

From my service I am returning an array of objects:

```
     data = [{id:1, value:25},{id:2, value:30}, {id:3, value:15} ]
```

Given the id:3 example, I need to say that amongst these data, based on value, I need to order the data and to know that id:3 is ranked 3rd( 30, 25, 14 - decreasing).
What would the best way be to do this? 
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: google “JavaScript Array Sort”

Comment: @Sphinx Thanks, I have done the sorting, I'm just not sure how to know..given the ID, what the rank is. How to calculate that part.

Comment: Given the sort and the I'd, you simply get the index of the item with that id. Perhaps research Array.filter, with the index passed to its filter function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### logic

1. sort the array of data using the [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method of arrays

   - `data.sort((a,b)=>{ return b.value - a.value })`

     - sorts puts object `a` at a lower index if `a` is lower (descending sort like you asked for)
2. get the index of a particular id

   - `data.map((obj)=>{return obj.id;}).indexOf(target_id)`

     - the `map` method converts [{id:3}, {id:1}, ...] to [3, 1, ]
     - the `indexOf` method finds the index of the first appearance of the target_id in the array

#### all together

```
var target_id = 3
data.sort((a,b)=>{ return b.value - a.value })
var rank = data.map(function(e) { return e.id; }).indexOf(target_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `.sort` over the difference between the values:

```js
const data = [{id:1, value:25},{id:2, value:30}, {id:3, value:15} ];
data.sort(({ value: vA }, { value: vB }) => vB - vA);
console.log(data);
```

If you need to figure out the rank, just iterate over the array after it's sorted:

```js
const data = [{id:1, value:25},{id:2, value:30}, {id:3, value:15} ];
data.sort(({ value: vA }, { value: vB }) => vB - vA);
data.forEach((item, i) => console.log(`Rank ${i + 1}: ${JSON.stringify(item)}`));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data
.map(function(d,i){return {index:d.id,value:d.value}})
.sort(function(a,b){return b.value - a.value})
.map(function(d,i){return data[d.index-1]})
```

[Some explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform)

Comment: What's the point of `map`ping twice when you can just `sort` on the plain array itself?

Comment: Why would just swapping property names out for other property names do anything but create an unnecessary step?

Comment: Have you done a peformance test, as this only makes sense if the compare function is expesive to compute.

Comment: 2nd sentence from the wikipedia page you've linked: *"This idiom is appropriate for comparison-based sorting when the ordering is actually based on the ordering of a certain property (the key) of the elements, **where computing that property is an intensive operation that should be performed a minimal number of times**"* This doesn't apply here. `value` ain't computed in some complicated way, it's a plain property on both the input data AND your mapped data

Comment: In this case the performance impact is minimal however it is a very good idea to use this form unless you have reason not to. It is surprising that nobody mentioned OP that sort mutates the array it is called on and this is not the case here also.

Comment: Its not really that suprising as the OP said `, I need to order the data`.    Saying all this the idea is still a good one.

Comment: I never got harmed from not mutating original objects. I will not refrain from advising others to do the same. It is a matter of choice.

Comment: ibowankenobi and others, Thank you so much. I read the comments and I genuinely learned something new. Though in this case, mutating was not an issue since I needed that order.
Thank you! )